# Bootstrap collapsing navbar menu vertically after having centered items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have an issue with my bootstrap navbar. I recently found a way to center items in the navbar but the fact is that when the menu is collapsed these items stay horizontally aligned instead of vertically.

Here is what i have at the moment :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top fixfollow center">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li>
                        <a class="navbar-brand visible-lg" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/link">link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/link">link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/link">link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/link">link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/link">link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

and the important css :

```
.center .nav,
 .center .nav > li
{
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    /*display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    /*zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
    vertical-align: top;
}


.center .navbar-inner {
    text-align:center;
}

.center .dropdown-menu {
    text-align: left;
}
```

With this I have my items centered in the navbar but displayed horizontally in the collpased menu. I want to have some help to change it in order to get back the classic behaviour ( i mean vertically ) of bootstrap collapsing menu without altering the centered items when the menu is not collapsed.

Comment: Please create fiddle menu so we can help in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply apply your rules inside of a media query:

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
   YOUR RULES HERE
}
```

See working example snippet.

```css
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .center .nav,
  .center .nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .center .navbar-inner {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .center .dropdown-menu {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top fixfollow center">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li>
              <a class="navbar-brand visible-lg" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/link">link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/link">link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/link">link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/link">link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/link">link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, try to change class *.dropdow-menu* (how's unset) by *.navbar-header* which have the dropdown-menu.